# Android Save view state after crash

Tags: android

MY application get crash for any reason one time but with same condition next time it working well means it not crash. For This I use Uncaught exception and through a error message and kill the process by using

```
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(10);
```

Now the problem is that, I have a number of Edit Text for Taking input from user capturing photos etc, at every crash application terminate and all data loose,
Now it is very irritating to fill again data. How to get rid of from this issue please Help

I want to save the state of the application when application crash,
and when I restart my application it should be start from last position where application got crash.

same as, working in application and if press Home Button, and restart application it start from last position of application where i press Home Button.

I am new in android development please help me, to get rid off from  such issue 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use preferences to save you values in android

Comment: Please post yout Logcat Stack Trace at time when your app crashes.

Comment: There area lot of fields check box radio button,so it is difficult to store in preferences.

Comment: I am not talking about any particular exception. I know exception can be handled and avoid crashes. But I want this for uncaught exception for future.